# use thymeleaf fragment variable to select i18n phrase

Tags: variables, internationalization, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and have localisation files set up and working fine, but for help I want to show help for the relevant page, so I am passing the page as a fragment variable.

I know I could use a th:switch/case and go through a bunch of options, but surely there is a quicker way?

So far any variation on this:

```
<p th:text="#{help.${page}}"></p>
```

only returns

```
??help.${page}_en??
```

instead of retrieving `help.page3=foo bar`, and displaying `foo bar`

I have already tried without second curly braces, and also adding in square braces, but so far no luck. Is there a nice shorthand that works? Or am I stuck with setting up a switch?

Yes I realise I could have written the switch 5 times by this point......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is expression [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing). You can do it as follows:

```
<p th:text="${__#{help.${page}}__}"></p>
```

Comment: ahh, preprocessing! That didn't quite work, but this variation did: 
<p th:text="#{help.__${page}__}"></p>

Comment: Sorry, i just misplaced the preprocessing tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need expression preprocessing on just the variable in question:

```
<p th:text="#{help.__${page}__}"></p>
```